# How To Visible Div Over Image

Tags: html, css

```css
    *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    .container{
     height: 638px;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-position: center;
     top: 0;
     z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .container img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 638px;
    }
    
    .container #short-des{
     background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     height: 400px;
     width: 500px;
     position: relative; 
    }
```

```html
     <div class="container">
     <img src="cover.jpg">
     <div id="short-des">
     
    </div>
    </div>
```

i want short-des div to visible over image at the center i tried z-index but it not working. please help me out to fix this with reason so i will take these things in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your div positioned `absolute` to overlap your image. Use `left`/`top`/`right`/`bottom` properties to set it's position.

It's position will be relative to closest non-static (absolute/relative/fixed) positioned element or `<body>`

```css
#short-des,
#short-des2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 250, 100, .6);
  z-index: 7;
}

#short-des2 {
  z-index: 8;
  left: 100px;
  top: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(250, 100, 100, .7);
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
  <div id="short-des"></div>
  <div id="short-des2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add image as background of container div [.container] as

```
    .container{
        background: url('path/to/image'); // eg. 'cover.jpg'
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        height: 638px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-position: center;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

and remove the `<img>` from html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="short-des"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is appropriate and it will help even in responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Just set `position : absolute` then set the location using `top` and `left` CSSproperties.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 638px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 638px;
}
.container div#short-des {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  top:40%;
  left:50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <div id="short-des">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 638px;
    height: 300px;
}
.box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.box #short-des{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

    <div id="short-des">

    </div>
    <img src="http://www.slowtrav.com/blog/girasoli/IMG_6820.JPG">
    <div id="short-des">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/rizwanmughal/pen/KgZQRx